# Pronorm of a finite solvable group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group. The *pronormaliser* of a subgroup $H$ in a group $G$, denoted  $P_G(H)$, is defined to be the set of elements of $G$ that pronormalise $H$. That is, $$P_G(H) = \{g \in G \; | \; \exists x\in \langle H, H^g \rangle\;\,\text{such that} \,\;H^x = H^g \}$$

Clearly, $H \,\text{prn}\, G \iff P_G(H) = G$.

From this we can define the *pronorm of G* as $$P(G) = \bigcap \limits_{H\in \Sigma} P_G(H)$$ where $\Sigma$ is the class of all subgroups of $G$.

**Definition**: The Wielandt subgroup of $G$ is defined to be the intersection of all the normalisers of the subnormal subgroups of $G$ i.e. $$\omega(G) = \bigcap_{H \triangleleft \triangleleft G} N_G(H).$$

Now we can define the *Lower Wielandt Series* by the **descending normal series** given by $w_0(G) = G$, $w_1(G)= w(G)$, $w_{\alpha +1}(G) = \hspace{-4mm}\bigcap \limits_{K\in \;\Omega_{\alpha}(G)}\hspace{-4mm}w(K)$ where $\Omega_{\alpha}(G)$ is the set of subgroups of $G$ that contain $w_\alpha(G)$. We denote the last term of this series by $\bar w(G)$

**Lemma 1**: Let $G$ be a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $H \leq K \leq G$. Then $P_K(H)= P_G(H) \cap K$

**Lemma 2.2.2**: Let $G$ be a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $H^K = H$. If $N \unlhd G$ such that $K \,\text{prn}\,KN$ and there exists $x\in N$ such that $x\in P_G(H)$, then $x \in P_G(HK)$

**Lemma 2.2.3**: Let $G$ be a finite solvable group and $P$ be a $p$-subgroup for some prime $p$. If $N \unlhd G$ such that $N \leq \omega(PN)$, then $P\,\text{prn}\,PN$

---

The following is Theorem and proof of a [research paper](http://elea.unisa.it/bitstream/handle/10556/174/tesi%20E.%20Romano.pdf;jsessionid=D01235B18288521A48173EC86277F659?sequence=1) which I am having a problem trying to understand:

**Theorem**: Let $G$ be a finite solvable group. Then $P(G) = \bar \omega(G)$

I have managed to show the inclusion $P(G) \subseteq \bar \omega(G)$. The reverse inclusion goes like this

[image]

> **Question**: I am not sure what the induction hypothesis is that author mentions induction on the order of $X$.

From $X' \,\text{prn}\, X'\bar\omega(G)$, From Lemma 1, I can deduce that $X'\bar\omega(G) = P_{X'\bar\omega(G)}(X') = P_G(X') \cap X'\bar\omega(G)$, and it follows $\bar\omega(G) \subseteq  P_G(X')$

> **Qusetion**: I can't seem to reason why $\bar\omega(G) \leq \omega(\langle x_i \rangle \bar\omega(G))$ in the proof which author says is clear.

Now $X'^{\langle x_i \rangle} = X'$. Also $\bar\omega(G) \unlhd G$ and $\bar\omega(G) \subseteq  P_G(X')$. Letting $H = X'$ and $K = \langle x_i \rangle$ in Lemma 2, we deduce that $\bar\omega(G) \subseteq P_G(\langle x_i \rangle X' = P_G( \langle x_i, X' \rangle)$

> **Question**: I can't seem to show how $X \,\text{prn}\, X\bar\omega(G)$ follows from applying Lemma 2.2.2 again.

Now $\langle x_i, X' \rangle \unlhd X$ since it contains $X'$. Using Lemma 1, $\bar \omega(G) \subseteq P_G(\langle x_i, X' \rangle) \cap X\bar \omega(G) = P_{X\bar \omega(G)}(\langle x_i, X' \rangle)$

Furthermore, $\langle x_i, X' \rangle \unlhd X$ implies that $\langle x_i, X' \rangle \,\text{prn}\,  X $ so that $X = P_X(\langle x_i, X' \rangle) = P_{X\bar \omega(G)}(\langle x_i, X' \rangle) \cap X$. From this we obtain $ X\bar \omega(G) = P_{X\bar \omega(G)}(\langle x_i, X' \rangle)$ i.e $\langle x_i, X' \rangle \,\text{prn}\,X\bar \omega(G)$.

I am sorry for the long post but I have been battling with this for a few days now. If someone could please try to help me with the questions that I have posted, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: For the first question, we are showing by induction on $|X|$ that $\bar{\omega}(X)$ is contained on the pronormalizer of $X$, so we can assume that this property holds for $X'$ since $|X'| \le |X|$.  I think the second question follows directly from the definition of the $\bar{\omega}$ as the final term of the Wielandt series.

Comment: I don't think Question 2 follow directly from the definition of $\bar \omega(G)$. I need to show that $\bar \omega(G)$ is contained in $N_{\langle xi \rangle \bar \omega(G)}(H)$ for each subnormal subgroup $H$ of $\langle xi \rangle \bar \omega(G)$. How do I proceed to show this?

Comment: $\bar{w}(G)$ is the intersection of $\omega(H)$ over all subgroups $H$ that contain $\bar{\omega}(G)$, and $\langle x_i \rangle\bar{\omega}(G)$ is a subgroup that contains $\bar{\omega}(G)$.

Comment: Okay for my last question, check my workings after the question. It shows that $\bar \omega(G) \subseteq P_G (\langle x_i, H'\rangle)$. Now $| \langle x_i, H' \rangle| \geq |H'|$, would it not follow by our induction that $ \bar \omega(G) \subseteq P_G(H)$?

Comment: I suggest reformulating it slightly and applying induction to the subgroup $\langle X',x_1,\ldots,x_{t-1} \rangle$ (which is still normal in $X$) rather than to $X'$. Then you only need apply Lemma 2.2.2 once to $K = \langle x_t \rangle$ to complete the proof.

Comment: Okay I'm a bit confused with the induction. In the proof we used induction on $X'$ because we know that $X' \neq X$ for a finite solvable group so $|X'| < |X|$, and therefore our induction hypothesis can be used. We can't be sure that $|\langle X', x_i, \dots, x_{t-1} \rangle|$ is strictly less than $|X|$ to use our induction hypothesis

Comment: Clearly we can choose the $x_i$ to make that hold.

Comment: @DerekHolt. Thank you. The proof works much better now